# DocuSign Signing Groups Limit - Creating and Deleting Groups on a per Envelope Basis

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently working to utilise DocuSign for enabling our clients to digitally sign paperwork.  The plan is to only use REST API for initiation and Connect webhooks for the responses.

For many clients, we have more than one contact email address. Since only one person needs to sign, I believe DocuSign's Signing Groups are required here.

I know the default maximum is 50 Signing Groups, which I could request to be increased, but I doubt that it is unlimited.  We could have thousands of clients and hundreds could have more than one contact email address, so predefining Signing Groups is not possible.

Is using the REST API to create a Signing Group for the client we are about to issue a document to, using it for Create Envelope and then immediately deleting it a viable option?

If a Signing Group is deleted immediately after Envelope creation, would it affect the Envelope in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let's clarify the difference between a "group mailbox" and a "signing group".

The former, is not a DocuSign object, but rather a feature of the mail service provider, allowing group@mail.com to go to multiple people.
The latter is a DocuSign object, allowing you to group together multiple unrelated email addresses so that only one of them is required to complete the transaction.

I believe in your scenario you have thousands of customers, each of them potentially has more than one email address, you want to send the envelope to a customer but only one of these emails addresses is required to complete the transaction. You need to use a signing group (not a group mailbox).

Deleting a signing group after an envelope was sent to it, even before the envelope is complete, will not negatively impact the envelope. So in that sense, your solution is a viable one.
The only concern I would have is the sheer number of API calls you'll have to make to create signing group, send envelope, delete signing group, and potentially additional calls (depending on your exact scenario) to just send a single envelope. Barring that issue - you should be ok.

Comment: I know the difference between Signing Groups and Group Mailboxes... one is obviously DocuSign functionality and the other doesn't have anything to do with DocuSign.  I just mentioned it to convey the fact that there is no pattern to the client contacts we have on file.   Apologies if that wasn't clear.  I don't need to mention Group Mailboxes as it has no relevance to my question, so I will edit that out :)

Comment: Other than network traffic and the overall complexity of our setup, are there any other downsides of having so many API calls?  I wouldn't expect there to be more than 1 or 2 envelopes being created every minute, and that is the full/peak throughput.

Are there any other alternatives for achieving this?

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any issues, the 3,000 API calls per hour is the concern I had, but with 1-2 per minute you should be fine...